# Fancybox Iframe gallery with css background images

Tags: iframe, background, fancybox, href, gallery

I am trying to get a gallery up and running just with css bacground images put in iframes in fancybox.

Thats what I use:

```
 $(".smallimg").click(
      function(){         
         var baseimg = $(this).css('background-image');
         var baseimg2 = baseimg.replace('url("','');
         var bgimg = baseimg2.replace('")','');          

        $.fancybox({
        helpers : {
            overlay : true
        },      
          width: '815px',
          height: '550px', 
          type: 'iframe',
          href: bgimg,
          fitToView: false, // 
          scrolling: 'no',
          iframe: {
            preload: false
        }

                 });             
      }
  );
```

And I have several divs holding images as background images witht the class .smallimg applied.

For clicking image by image my code works quite good but I would like to have it in gallery style... is that possible?

Need to mention that the names of the images are NOT enumerated like 1.jpg 2.jpg ...

Rgds

Mirko

Comment: Why are you opening images as `iframe`??

Comment: its because I got them as backgrounds in divs

Comment: It doesn't really matter, they are still images

Comment: Okay perfect I got rid of that iframe. Another problem is now that I want to resize the image when resizing the browser window. So I eliminated the fixed height and width and set autoHeight : true, autoWidth  : true, fitToView: true. Its resizing the fancybox image frame but not the image itself.